# Extend object inside of trait in Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, scala-2.10

I've the following code:

```
trait AcceptExtractors {

  /**
   * Common extractors to check if a request accepts JSON, Html, etc.
   * Example of use:
   * {{{
   * request match {
   *   case Accepts.Json() => Ok(toJson(value))
   *   case _ => Ok(views.html.show(value))
   * }
   * }}}
   */
  object Accepts {
    import play.api.http.MimeTypes
    val Json = Accepting(MimeTypes.JSON)
    val Html = Accepting(MimeTypes.HTML)
    val Xml = Accepting(MimeTypes.XML)
    val JavaScript = Accepting(MimeTypes.JAVASCRIPT)
  }

}
```

Is there any way to extend the Accepts object?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.

`Object`s are single values. If they could be extended, they would not be singletons (*). The class generated to represent them is final, so even if you knew its name (not hard to find out), you could not extend it.

(*) `Object`s are only truly singletons when defined at global scope or nested strictly within other `object`s leading back to a global one.

Comment: Hm. But if Accepts wouldn't be inside a trait I could do MyAccepts extends Accepts. Right? But it's not possible because it's inside a trait?

Comment: No. You will never be able to use an `object` in an `extends` clause.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you could make Accepts a trait which you can extend.

Comment: It's code from a library ... I like to have my own object like MyAccepts, which contains alle the vals from AcceptExtractors.Accepts